# Как декодировать JSON объект через Codable, в котором может быть свойство ПУСТОЙ массив?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть модель картинки:

```
struct Image : Decodable {
let id: String
let name : String
let uri : String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "_id"
    case name
    case uri
}
```

}

Есть главный объект, в котором есть массив объектов Image (свойство img).

```
class MyObject : Decodable {
let id : String
let description : String
let fullAddress : String
let location: GoogleLocation?
let name: String?
let timeClose: String?
let timeOpen : String?
var img : [Image]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "_id"
    case description
    case fullAddress
    case location
    case name
    case timeClose
    case timeOpen
    case img
}
```

Так получилось, что если у объекта нет картинок, возвращается пустой массив, а не объект без свойства img, поэтому установка свойства img в опциональное не помогает. При декодировании при встрече пустого массива вылетает следующая ошибка :

Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(Swift.KeyedDecodingContainer, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 10", intValue: 10), CodingKeys(stringValue: "img", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, у Вас в массиве имеются `null` вместо `Image`, а не пустой массив.

Попробуйте:

```
var img : [Image?]
```

Comment: Вы правы, огромное спасибо!

Comment: не подскажете, почему у класса, который подписывается на Codable, компилятор продолжает требовать создание инициализатора? приходится писать большой неиспользуемый init..

Comment: @АртемКолядин для класса необходимо создавать инициализатор, если есть константные и не проинициализированные поля. Т.е.  вариант не писать инициализатор - только если все поля optional или все поля проинициализированные переменные. Структура же предоставляет инициализатор по умолчанию.

Comment: в таком случае лучше сразу написать инициализатор, чтобы потом не прописывать безопасные извлечения опцианалов и вспоминать, какие свойства точно можно извлечь через !, а какие лучше через guard let ?

Comment: @АртемКолядин у Codable свои инициализаторы, одно другому не мешает. Ну и лучше не использовать `force unwrap` вообще, особенно если данные получены невесть откуда.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!